# Return 404 with nginx to all locations except for one

Tags: php, nginx

I've created a subdomain to host our API. I'm trying to figure out how to configure nginx to only allow requests to the API location (/2/, which would look like https://api.example.com/2/) and return 404s for all other requests to api.example.com

We're using PHP with a pretty standard PHP setup--routing most requests through index.php and matching php as show below:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php last;
        }


location ~ \.php$ { config here; }
```

I'm hoping I'm over-thinking this and that there is a simple solution.

Comment: This question originally had two answers. I commented on both because they each had merit. After more testing, the second answer may actually be the one I need, but it is now deleted (I assume by the poster). I'm sure this is a long shot, but can the original poster (can't recall who) undelete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just configure the `/2` location and mark every thing else as 404

```
location / {
    return 404;
}
location /2 {
    try_files $uri /2/index.php$request_uri;
}
location ~ \.php$ { config here; }
```

Comment: I just tested this out and got it working for my liking. The way we have it set up the main index page will still load, but that works as we'll show a dev page there instead of the standard index page.

Comment: i don't really understand what you meant, but i just noticed that i used `@uri` which is wrong, it should be `$uri`, so i'm changing my answer to that.